# Unable to install libopencv-nonfree-dev in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I tried to install the `libopencv-nonfree-dev` package in Ubuntu 16.04 using the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:xqms/opencv-nonfree
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libopencv-nonfree-dev
```

But I got the error below:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> libopencv-nonfree-dev : Depends: libopencv-features2d-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1xqms2~xenial1) but 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
>
> Depends: libopencv-nonfree2.4v5 (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1xqms2~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

What could I do to install it then?

Answer (score 2):

I had some success with [this alternative PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jeff250/+archive/ubuntu/opencv). For completeness, I removed the other one first. I also had to reinstall the main OpenCV package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:xqms/opencv-nonfree
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:jeff250/opencv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
sudo apt-get install libopencv-nonfree-dev
```

Comment: yeah it worked!! Thanks entheh.